# detecting and computing the intersection of lines and planes with a torus

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I have a variety of related questions that all seem to involve deeper math that I'm used to dealing with (undergraduate calculus and linear algebra). My feeling is that these are classical (and solved) questions in (advanced) analytic geometry.

Consider a fixed ball $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and some axis of rotation $\mathbf{a}$.

I) For an arbitrary plane $\pi$, determine the set of angles $\theta$ for which the rotated ball intersects the plane. A little easier (but still beyond me); determine if that set is empty. This second problem seems to require finding the (smallest) distance from the plane $\pi$ to a point on a circle (the trajectory of the ball centre under the given rotation). That seemingly elementary problem still eludes me.

II) Same as I, but with an arbitrary line $l$ instead of the plane $\pi$.

There are a lot of special cases to consider, so I am happy to focus on the particular case where the ball has radius 1 and is centered at (2,0,0) and the axis of rotation is the positive z-axis.

Thanks.

Comment: When the ball is rotated, the result isn't a torus. A torus is the result of rotating a *circle* (in 3-d space) about an axis through the center of the circle and perpendicular to the plane of the circle.

Comment: A plane or line intersects the ball if its distance to the center is less than (or equal to, if including the boundary) the ball’s radius. A quick web search should give you standard formulas for computing this distance.

Comment: So, it the plane and line that are being rotated?

Comment: The plane / line are fixed. The ball is rotated about the given axis. The question is, does the rotated ball intersect the plane/line?

Comment: The solution is the same: compute the distance to the rotated center.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question(s). For the plane case, I am asking for (a) a set of angles and (b) whether or not the (fixed) plane intersects any rotated ball. You seem to think that I'm asking for the distance from a given ball to a given plane. That is indeed an elementary problem.

Comment: A sphere intersects a plane when the distance of its center to the plane is less than or equal to the radius. Given any angle of rotation, your intersection problem then devolves to solving the elementary (as you’ve deem them) problems of rotating a point and computing its distance to a fixed plane.